# How to compare open and close price variables in this dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe which has open, high, low, close and date of each minute for over 5 years. I want to calculate a new column and want to compare (close - open)  close price (of that minute) with the open price of that day (9:15am). How do I do that?

Below is the screenshot of the file. In `J` column I have the open price of the day and `K` column is the running close. I want to compute the difference between close and open. This file has 0.7 million rows and more than 1000 days which means Open price will change 1000 times.

I have 200 such similar files where I need to do the same procedure and thus loop is not the desired solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `groupby` and `transform`. Note that this assumes that your data is sorted (e.g., the first value of each group is the open price).

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# sample date
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ticker': ['A']*5,
                    'date': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', periods=5),
                    'time': [datetime.time(9, 15), datetime.time(9, 16), datetime.time(9, 17),
                             datetime.time(9, 18), datetime.time(9, 19)],
                    'open': [1,2,3,4,5],
                    'close': [2,3,4,3,2]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ticker': ['A']*5,
                    'date': pd.date_range('2020-01-02', '2020-01-02', periods=5),
                    'time': [datetime.time(9, 15), datetime.time(9, 16), datetime.time(9, 17),
                             datetime.time(9, 18), datetime.time(9, 19)],
                    'open': [3,2,3,4,5],
                    'close': [2,3,4,3,2]})

df = df1.append(df2)


# groupby the ticker and date then use transform to get the first value
# subtract the close from the first value of each group
df['diff'] = df['close'] - df.groupby(['ticker', 'date'])['open'].transform('first')

  ticker       date      time  open  close  diff
0      A 2020-01-01  09:15:00     1      2     1
1      A 2020-01-01  09:16:00     2      3     2
2      A 2020-01-01  09:17:00     3      4     3
3      A 2020-01-01  09:18:00     4      3     2
4      A 2020-01-01  09:19:00     5      2     1
0      A 2020-01-02  09:15:00     3      2    -1
1      A 2020-01-02  09:16:00     2      3     0
2      A 2020-01-02  09:17:00     3      4     1
3      A 2020-01-02  09:18:00     4      3     0
4      A 2020-01-02  09:19:00     5      2    -1
```